# cant import .pst file to outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

i try to import contacts from one computer to another,

when i try to import the file, i get this error:

" ..personal pst file in use by this user..."

what can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get past the file lock, you can **EXPORT** your current outlook pst form outlook to a new pst.

**FILE/IMPORT AND EXPORT/**  to open the EXPORT WIZARD, then **EXPORT TO A FILE** and so on.

For that matter, you could likely just make a copy of the pst using windows **FILE / COPY / PASTE** and open the copy on the new computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file isn't already open. If you closed the PST file already, close and reopen Outlook to release the file lock.

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager (Ctrl + Alt + Delete) and go to the Processes tab, end any process titled outlook.exe. That should kill anything using the PST file.